# Cross browser ellipsing of multiline text

Tags: css, ellipsis

I want multiline text longer than two lines to truncate by ellipsing on all browsers. `text-overflow: ellipsis` does not work for multiline text. Using `line-clamp` property does not work on IE, Edge and Firefox as its not supported on those browsers yet.
I referred to http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/ and used the following

```
@mixin multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.2em, $lineCount: 1, $bgColor: white){
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  line-height: $lineHeight;
  max-height: $lineHeight * $lineCount;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  &:before {
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    background: $bgColor;
  }
}

.multiline-ellipsis {
  @include multiLineEllipsis($lineHeight: 1.4em, $lineCount: 2);
}
```

This now ellipses text longer than two lines on all browsers including IE, Edge and Firefox but its adding extra space between words in the text. How can this be fixed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

css word-spacing property specifies the space between words and you can use relative (negative) value to reduce the justifying space:

```
text-align:justify;
word-spacing:-2px;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp